# How long should refrigerator defrosting take?

Tags: repair

How long does it take for the tubing between the freezer and the refrigerator to thaw? My freezer works just fine, but my refrigerator isn't keeping items cold.  I unplugged it so it can thaw the tubing that blows the cold air from the freezer to the refrigerator.  Just need to know approximately how long it needs to be kept unplugged.

Answer (score 1):

It should not take more than a couple of hours.  If it still doesn't work, you can remove the cover off the evaporator in the back of your freezer and check to be sure.  Your evaporator blower may also have stopped working, or the motor may be so weak it isn't moving air properly.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had my 2017 Whirlpool bottom freezer refrigerator ice up and appears to have taken three hours with a hair dryer running to defrost it. The coils for this refrigerator are on the back wall of the freezer compartment. . Supposedly the newer refrigerators have a much tighter "air conditioner" evaporator coils which can hold onto the ice much more tightly than the older style of coiled evaporator with metal fringe. The repair technician said it would take 48 hours with the refrigerator off and the doors open to defrost. I'm not sure if that was worst case scenario or something else.

This fridge replaced a approximately 2000 year old refrigerator with the older style coils between the fridge and freezer sections which with disassembly I could defrost in under an hour.

Comment: I don't see this being worthy of a down vote. The answer gave an example of time and additional information on how they defrosted a fridge.

Comment: Question deleted